# Why does numpy.broadcast "transpose" results of vstack and similar functions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

Observe:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
In [3]: np.vstack([x, x])
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])

In [4]: np.vstack(np.broadcast(x, x))
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Similarly for `column_stack` and `row_stack` (`hstack` behaves differently in this case but it also differs when used with broadcast). Why?

I'm after the logic behind that rather than finding a way of "repairing" this behavior (I'm just fine with it, it's just unintuitive).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.broadcast` returns an instance of an iterator object that describes *how* the arrays should be broadcast together.<sup>1</sup> Among other things, it describes the shape and the number of dimensions that the resulting array will have.

Crucially, when you actually *iterate* over this object in Python you get back tuples of elements from each input array:

```
>>> b = np.broadcast(x, x)
>>> b.shape
(3,)
>>> b.ndim
1
>>> list(b)
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

This tells us that if we were performing an actual operation on the arrays (say, `x+x`) NumPy would return an array of shape `(3,)`, one dimension and combine the elements in the tuple to produce the values in the final array (e.g. it would perform `1+1`, `2+2`, `3+3` for the addition).

If you dig in to the source of `vstack` you find that [all it does](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.10.1/numpy/core/shape_base.py#L230) is make sure the elements of the iterable that it has been given are at least two-dimensional, and then stack them along axis 0.

In the case of `b = np.broadcast(x, x)` this means that we get the following arrays to stack:

```
>>> [np.atleast_2d(_m) for _m in b]
[array([[1, 1]]), array([[2, 2]]), array([[3, 3]])]
```

These three small arrays are then stacked vertically producing the output you note.

---

<sup>1</sup> Exactly how arrays of varying dimensions are iterated over in parallel is at the very heart of how NumPy's broadcasting works. The code can be found mostly in [iterators.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c39c90bf8716bbba75751279d7e03d84dd8e66f0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/iterators.c). An interesting overview of NumPy's multidimensional iterator, written by Travis Oliphant himself, can be found in the [Beautiful Code](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gJrmszNHQV4C&lpg=PA307&ots=rMT2suXcof&dq=beautiful%20code%20numpy&pg=PA303#v=onepage&q&f=false) book.

Comment: It's interesting that `np.concatenate(np.broadcast(...))` does not work.  The list comprehension that `vstack` (and relatives) does is necessary.  `np.array(list(np.broadcast(...)))` does work, and is faster.